# Core Graphics: Mask Image, add Overlay and Underlay

Tags: ios, core-graphics

How can I mask an image, add an overlay and an underlay to the masked image with Core Graphics? (for instance: a document icon consists out of a mask png, a page curl png and a base with shadow) Can someone give me a best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Draw the underlay with `CGContextDrawImage()`.
- Push a graphics context state with `CGContextSaveGState()`.
- Load the mask and add it to the context using `CGContextClipToMask()`.
- Draw your content.
- Pop the graphics context with `CGContextRestoreGState()`.
- Draw your overlay image with `CGContextDrawImage()`.